# pandas Series - max/min of every value in

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following:

```
a = pd.Series([4, 8, 3, 6, 2])
b = pd.Series([2, 6, 6, 3, 4])
```

I can do:

```
c = a.sub(b)

print c
0  2
1  2
2 -3
3  3
4 -2
```

What I really want is to take the min of that and generate the following series:

```
0  2
1  2
2  0
3  3
4  0
```

Can I do following using pandas Series math without iterating through every value explicitly like:

```
result = []
for val in c.tolist():
    result.append(val if val > 0 else 0)
pd.Series(result)
```

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions.  Instead, simply open another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
In [35]: a.sub(b).clip(lower=0)
Out[35]:
0    2
1    2
2    0
3    3
4    0
dtype: int64
```